# Is it possible, in C++, to do some funky stuff when calling my function to return different types depending on my program's needs?

Tags: c++, casting

Consider the useful code by Zaita posted at [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/), in particular the part which gets numbers safely, modified to be a function in my case:

```
int get_number()
{
   /**
    * cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046
    * gets number from input stream
    **/

   string input = "";
   int number = 0;

   while (true)
   {
      getline(cin, input);
      stringstream checks(input);
      if (checks >> number)
         return number;
      cout << "Please enter a valid number\n";
   }
}
```

Now, my question is this: Can I remove the `int` on the first line of the function definition for get_number(), and declare it at the top of my code with all the types I might want to return such as doing some declarations like this:

```
double get_number();
int get_number();
long get_number();
unsigned short get_number();
...
...
```

And somehow get it to do different returns depending on the variable I want to store the return from the function with? Currently I simply writing multiple definitions of essentially the same function while changing the name to `get_someType`

I am hoping I can do something like declare with this sort of syntax:

```
int get_number(int);
double get_double(double);
...
...
```

And my desire would be to do something like:

```
int x;
x = get_number(int);
```

I am sure this will NOT work however! Because it would be impossible to define the function's source code with parameters with no names...

Comment: @zmbq Given that I am so new to this language, perhaps you could share a link on templates that you find useful, and helps me find the solution easier?

Comment: One tricky thing you need to watch out for: **you must know the type you want to return at compile time** if you use the function templates method.  In other words, the caller must know (hard-code) exactly the type it wants returned.  If you need to *dynamically* return the type (letting the function decide the type), you need to use something like boost::variant or wrap all the return types in a union/class yourself, and do a lot of manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [function `template`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)!

This code is buggy (please don't use cplusplus.com as a reference), since it doesn't check that input from `std::cin` is received.

A templated example would look something like this (untested):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
T get_number()
{
    std::string input = "";
    T number; // Don't initialise to zero
    bool done = false;

    while (!done)
    {
        if (std::getline(std::cin, input)) // check for success
        {
            std::istringstream checks(input);
            if (checks >> number)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Please enter a valid number\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("No input was received\n");
        }
    }
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int i = get_number<int>();
        float f = get_number<float>();
        double d = get_number<double>();
        char b = get_number<char>();
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

To incorporate my comment below into this answer...  In a class template or function template, `typename` can be used as an alternative to `class` to declare templated types. I prefer [**`typename`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) because we're dealing with POD-types and not `class`es.

Comment: Why would you use a non-numeric type with a function called `get_number()`? No... some error checking will be needed if this is called as `<std::string>` or `char*` or ... .

Comment: that's what I am trying to tell you.. error checking. Or remove the 'T number =0;` and say `T number;`.

Comment: Interesting that the other answer uses `template <class T>` while you are using `<typename T>` nice example, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Aniket: cplusplus.com is a dangerous source of information, I've included a comment in the code now.

Comment: @Leonardo: In a class template or function template, `typename` can be used as an alternative to `class` to declare templated types. I prefer `typename` because we're dealing with POD-types and not `class`es.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, the get_number implementation you've found is badly written: what do you think happens when you get an EOF on input?  It spins around printing "Please enter a valid number\n" as fast as it can until you kill the program....

Secondly, you can't overload on return type - which means you can't have functions that only differ in the return type.

Finally, C++ has templates that can do what I think you want...

```
template <typename T>
bool get(T& x)
{
    std::string input;
    if (!getline(std::cin, input))
        return false;
    stringstream checks(input);
    if (checks >> x)
        return true;
    cout << "Please enter a valid value\n";
}
```

You can then use `if (get(my_int)) ...` or `if (get(my_double))` etc..

As input can not be guaranteed to succeed, you really should either provide a boolean return type (as illustrated) or throw an exception once it's clear input can not succeed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a flaw in that code, I have for some time now been trying to figure out how to make the loop no longer infinite. But it seems I cannot do `while(!(checks >> number))` because I cannot figure out how to declare the `stringstream` type.

Comment: @Leonardo: You should really use `std::istringstream` from the `sstream` header, as used in my answer. Tony's code gets my vote :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with templates.

Here you can find out some template tutorials for beginners (start from 58..)
    http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=16

Comment: Cool link, I really appreciate that!

Comment: i used it when i'm started the c++. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates, but as far as I know your function must have an argument of the type of that template as well, as in:

```
template <class T>
T get_number(T arg)
{
   /**
    * cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046
    * gets number from input stream
    **/

   string input = "";
   T number = 0;

   while (true)
   {
      getline(cin, input);
      stringstream checks(input);
      if (checks >> number)
         return number;
      cout << "Please enter a valid number\n";
   }
}
```

The type of template (`T`) is resolved in compile time based on the type of argument passed to the function.

Comment: what if I say non-numeric type for the template? will `T number = 0` work?

Comment: Do I have to use the keywords `template <class myTypeID>` before every function I use templates with, or is it possible this will affect multiple functions below it? Perhaps using brackets for example after the first line in your example?

Comment: No, you have to use if for every function individually.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
T get_number()
{
   /**
    * cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046
    * gets number from input stream
    **/

   string input = "";
   T genericobj;

   while (true)
   {
      getline(cin, input);
      stringstream checks(input);
      if (checks >> genericobj)
         return genericobj;
      cout << "Please enter a valid input\n" ;
   }
}
```